# How to get item id from sharepoint lookup column allowing multiple selection

Tags: lookup-column, item, multiple-values

How can I get the individual item id from sharepoint lookup column that allows multiple selection. For instance the data is stored as 1479 in sharepoint which would represent items id 1,4,7 and 9.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Specifically, it would be helpful if you could elaborate on the specific problem you are facing, any error messages you have encountered while working with your code or approach, and if possible, include any code snippets you have already tried. This additional information will enable me to better understand your situation and provide a more accurate response.